# Slide images automatically.

Tags: android

I have created a demo project to slide images. I need the images to slide automatically once i open my application. I'm posting my code below.

activity_page_view  (Main Layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100pt"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

PageViewActivity(Main Activity)

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PageViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
    ViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_view);

        List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();

        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    }


    private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance(1));
        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance(2));
        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance(3));
        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance(4));
        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance(5));
        return fList;
    }
}
```

MyFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String IMAGE_URL = "IMAGE_URL";
    TextView messageTextView;
    ImageView imageView;

    public ArrayList<String> UrlsImage = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> TagLine = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static MyFragment newInstance(Integer index)
    {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putInt(IMAGE_URL,index);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       int index = getArguments().getInt(IMAGE_URL);



        UrlsImage.add("http://itradar.ir/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/root-android-5.jpg");
        UrlsImage.add("http://www.pcwebim.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Android.jpg");
        UrlsImage.add("http://www.androidrootguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Stock-Android-Wallpapers-Download.jpg");
        UrlsImage.add("https://ardroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/wpaper1294246633612.jpg");
        UrlsImage.add("http://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/w550h500/public/wallpapers/black-lloyd-7dk.jpg?itok=bGsIaB2R");


        TagLine.add("Android Pirate");
        TagLine.add("Android Alien");
        TagLine.add("Android Perfect");
        TagLine.add("Android Halloween");
        TagLine.add("Android Black");





        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);
        messageTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(UrlsImage.get(index-1))
                .into(imageView);

        messageTextView.setText(TagLine.get(index-1));

        return v;
    }

}
```

MyPageAdapter (Custom adapter)

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;


public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm,List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments=fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

myfragment_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/imageview"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where should i change the code.
Hoping help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute that by using handler and timer like this in `onCreate()` :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (position == TOTAL_FRAMENT- 1) {
                    position = 0;
                } else {
                    position++;
                }
                pager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
            }
        };

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(update);
            }
        }, 100, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might be interested in a [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). It's basically a FrameLayout with an animator.

From the docs:

> Simple ViewAnimator that will animate between two or more views that
>   have been added to it. Only one child is shown at a time. If
>   requested, can automatically flip between each child at a regular
>   interval.

Answer (score 0):

> Simply add this method to your **Activity/Fragment**

```
private Runnable update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //get the position from viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener
                if (position == mAdapter.getCount()- 1) {
                    position = 0;
                } else {
                    position++;
                }
                pager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
                handler.post(update);
            }
        };
```

and in `onCreate` simply call it once

```
new Handler().postDelayed(update,1000);
```